# Django - Default Authentication Allowany is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

Here I am using django with default authentication.
My authentication class in settings.py is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ],
}
```

I set it as a default authentication

but for some API, I don't need Authentication at that time I use allow any but it is not working
it required Token like

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

My code for POST method is

```
class EnquiryCrudPost(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        UserData = request.data
        authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
        permission_classes = (AllowAny)
        if UserData:
            try:
                NewUserData = Enquiry.objects.create()
                ..........
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes` should be defined as ***class attributes***, not within your method. Also, it should be `list` or `tuple`

```
class EnquiryCrudPost(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,) # you were missing a comma
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)# you were missing a comma

    def post(self, request):
        ...
```

In this particular case, the **`authentication_classes`** is not really matter since you wish to use the `AllowAny`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @JPG, since you have a class based view, you need to define your permission classes and authentication classes outside your method. Also `AllowAny` comes under `permission_classes` and not under `authentication_classes`.

In case you had a function based view, you could use a decorator outside the function definition like so

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

Here's some documentation that'll help you understand permission and authentication classes better
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions